# Fill In Array With Values From Lookup Table

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm writing a piece of code that takes an array of numbers and builds an x by x
array of their products.

Since the grid the values in the grid are symmetrical, I'm thinking about computing half the grid, and then filling in the missing items using a lookup table.

I have an array of values that looks like this:

```
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [4,6,8,10],
  [9,12,15],
  [16,20],
  [25]
```

I'm trying to build an array that looks like this:

```
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [2,4,6,8,10],
  [3,6,9,12,15],
  [4,8,12,16,20],
  [5,10,15,20,25]
```

I wrote a piece of code that can take an x,y coordinate, and lookup the correct value.

```
class MultiplicationTable

  def initialize(num_ary)
    @num_ary = num_ary.to_a
  end

  def lookup_table
    @num_ary.map do |x|
      @num_ary[(x-1)..-1].map do |y|
        x * y
      end 
    end
  end

  def lookup(a,b)
    lookup_table[a][b-a] 
  end
end
```

Is there a good way in ruby to efficiently produce the second array from the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fill out the rest of the table would be

1. add `ary[0][1]` to the front of `ary[1]`
2. then add `ary[1][2]` and `ary[0][2]` to the front of `ary[2]`
3. then add `ary[2][3]`, `ary[1][3]`, and `ary[0][3]` to the front of `ary[3]`.
4. etc...

It's a simple pattern, where each row counts down through the previous rows:

```
ary.each_with_index do |row, i|
  (1..i).each { |j| row.unshift ary[i - j][i] }
end
```

That's the answer to your question, but do you really need to fill out the rest of the array at all? Since it is always symmetrical, why waste time and memory by populating it?

```
def lookup(a, b)
  a, b = b, a if b < a
  lookup_table[a][b - a]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out in a little bit. To answer your question, I need to print out the complete table.